# How to compose an algorithm to create new array (based on array data), if I need a reference to an array being created, no for loop, in mathematica?

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming, functional

I have an array with either 1 or 0. From this, I am trying to create a new array with intervals.

I have some base interval, one step, we can say 1 second here. If there is 0, I skip, if there is 1 I create an interval based on a position, which means if 1 is in the first place of the input array, I'll create interval {1, 2} and then if the next one is also 1, I'll change the first interval to {1,3}.

I wrote this code that works, but I am trying to figure out a better way using functional methods like Fold/MapIndexed/Select to get the final array but it hurts my OOP brain

In:

```
fsetIntervalList[interval_, data_] := Module[{v = interval, d = data},
  array = {}; 
  For[i = 0, i < Length[d], i++, 
   If[d[[i + 1]] == 0, Continue[], 
    If[i == 0 || d[[i]] == 0, AppendTo[array, {i*v, i*v + v}], 
     array[[Length[array]]][[2]] += v]]
   ];
  Return[array]
  ]
```

In:

```
fsetIntervalList[0.25, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}]
```

Out:

```
{{0., 0.25}, {0.75, 1.25}}
```

Comment: Output: `{ }` ?

Comment: The first output was `{ }`, missed `;` behind `array = {};` so there should be only one output, by calling `array`. Which is not the best obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I cannot say that I understand your explanation. Perhaps someone with a better understanding of this particular problem will respond to your post. In order to help that person, please add to your post the  input for which you show this `array` output.

Comment: thanks @Syed I understand my code might have been the most confusing thing there, I edited it to use Module and return the actual output from the method. I hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fsetIntervalList[v_, bits_] :=
 With[{g = SplitBy[Range@Length@bits, bits[[#]] &]},
  {#[[1]], #[[1]] + Length@#} v & /@ (Select[g, bits[[#]][[1]] == 1 &] - 1)]
```

```
fsetIntervalList[0.25, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}]
(* {{0., 0.25}, {0.75, 1.25}} *)
```

Comment: The clever bit here is to do: `SplitBy[Range@Length@bits, bits[[#]] &]` which takes a list of positions {1,2,3,4,...,n} and splits them into runs where there are corresponding runs in the bits list, so {1,0,0,1,1,0} groups as {{1},{0,0},{1,1},{0}} which gives positions {{1},{2,3},{4,5},{6}}. You then just select the groups for the 1s only and -1 to zero-index your positions. The last thing to do is multiply and add  v to get your intervals.